# numpy - what is recursor in numpy/core/arrayprint.pyarrayprint.py and why it costs time?

Tags: performance, numpy

## Question

What is `recursor` in `numpy/core/arrayprint.pyarrayprint.py` and why it costs time? Appreciate if there is a resource

## Background

Noticed that calculating softmax `exp(x) / sum(exp(X))` is taking time and run the profiler.

```
def softmax(X: Union[np.ndarray, float]) -> Union[np.ndarray, float]:
    C = np.max(X, axis=-1, keepdims=True) 
    exp = np.exp(X - C)    # to prevent overflow
    return exp / np.sum(exp, axis=-1, keepdims=True)


profiler = cProfile.Profile()
profiler.enable()

for _ in range(1000):
    softmax(X)

profiler.disable()
profiler.print_stats(sort="cumtime")
```

Apparently it spends majority of time in arrayprint.py especially in recurser. Hence wonder what is arrayprint and if there is a way to improve the performance.

```
129000/3000    0.335    0.000    1.106    0.000 arrayprint.py:718(recurser)
```

#### Entire profiler output.

```
2419006 function calls (2275006 primitive calls) in 2.158 seconds

   Ordered by: cumulative time

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
     1000    0.136    0.000    2.158    0.002 functions.py:173(softmax)
     3000    0.006    0.000    1.966    0.001 arrayprint.py:1473(_array_str_implementation)
     3000    0.013    0.000    1.960    0.001 arrayprint.py:516(array2string)
     3000    0.013    0.000    1.926    0.001 arrayprint.py:461(wrapper)
     3000    0.022    0.000    1.908    0.001 arrayprint.py:478(_array2string)
     3000    0.005    0.000    1.111    0.000 arrayprint.py:709(_formatArray)
129000/3000    0.335    0.000    1.106    0.000 arrayprint.py:718(recurser)
     3000    0.016    0.000    0.677    0.000 arrayprint.py:409(_get_format_function)
     3000    0.005    0.000    0.651    0.000 arrayprint.py:366(<lambda>)
     3000    0.012    0.000    0.646    0.000 arrayprint.py:836(__init__)
     3000    0.112    0.000    0.632    0.000 arrayprint.py:863(fillFormat)
   108000    0.368    0.000    0.588    0.000 arrayprint.py:947(__call__)
   216000    0.395    0.000    0.395    0.000 {built-in method numpy.core._multiarray_umath.dragon4_positional}
   111000    0.053    0.000    0.323    0.000 arrayprint.py:918(<genexpr>)
   111000    0.075    0.000    0.249    0.000 arrayprint.py:913(<genexpr>)
   126000    0.110    0.000    0.152    0.000 arrayprint.py:695(_extendLine)
    17000    0.034    0.000    0.134    0.000 {built-in method numpy.core._multiarray_umath.implement_array_function}
    24000    0.040    0.000    0.096    0.000 {built-in method builtins.max}
21000/3000    0.043    0.000    0.094    0.000 arrayprint.py:324(_leading_trailing)
     8000    0.017    0.000    0.085    0.000 fromnumeric.py:70(_wrapreduction)
   960000    0.078    0.000    0.078    0.000 {built-in method builtins.len}
     4000    0.005    0.000    0.071    0.000 <__array_function__ internals>:2(amax)
     8000    0.062    0.000    0.062    0.000 {method 'reduce' of 'numpy.ufunc' objects}
     4000    0.008    0.000    0.062    0.000 fromnumeric.py:2589(amax)
     9000    0.008    0.000    0.037    0.000 <__array_function__ internals>:2(concatenate)
     6000    0.013    0.000    0.034    0.000 _ufunc_config.py:32(seterr)
   111000    0.021    0.000    0.029    0.000 arrayprint.py:922(<genexpr>)
   111000    0.020    0.000    0.027    0.000 arrayprint.py:923(<genexpr>)
     3000    0.004    0.000    0.025    0.000 _ufunc_config.py:433(__enter__)
     3000    0.003    0.000    0.025    0.000 <__array_function__ internals>:2(amin)
   108000    0.021    0.000    0.021    0.000 {method 'split' of 'str' objects}
     1000    0.002    0.000    0.021    0.000 <__array_function__ internals>:2(sum)
     3000    0.004    0.000    0.020    0.000 fromnumeric.py:2714(amin)
     3000    0.009    0.000    0.018    0.000 arrayprint.py:60(_make_options_dict)
     1000    0.003    0.000    0.018    0.000 fromnumeric.py:2105(sum)
     3000    0.003    0.000    0.015    0.000 _ufunc_config.py:438(__exit__)
     6000    0.012    0.000    0.013    0.000 _ufunc_config.py:132(geterr)
    18000    0.008    0.000    0.012    0.000 index_tricks.py:727(__getitem__)
     3000    0.007    0.000    0.007    0.000 arrayprint.py:358(_get_formatdict)
     3000    0.007    0.000    0.007    0.000 {built-in method builtins.locals}
    27000    0.006    0.000    0.006    0.000 {method 'rstrip' of 'str' objects}
    24000    0.006    0.000    0.006    0.000 {built-in method builtins.isinstance}
     6000    0.006    0.000    0.006    0.000 {built-in method numpy.seterrobj}
     8000    0.005    0.000    0.005    0.000 fromnumeric.py:71(<dictcomp>)
     3000    0.002    0.000    0.004    0.000 _asarray.py:14(asarray)
    12000    0.003    0.000    0.003    0.000 {built-in method numpy.geterrobj}
     1000    0.002    0.000    0.003    0.000 __init__.py:1412(debug)
     3000    0.002    0.000    0.002    0.000 arrayprint.py:65(<dictcomp>)
    11000    0.002    0.000    0.002    0.000 {method 'items' of 'dict' objects}
     3000    0.002    0.000    0.002    0.000 {built-in method numpy.array}
    12000    0.002    0.000    0.002    0.000 {built-in method builtins.issubclass}
     3000    0.002    0.000    0.002    0.000 {method 'update' of 'dict' objects}
     9000    0.002    0.000    0.002    0.000 multiarray.py:143(concatenate)
     3000    0.002    0.000    0.002    0.000 _ufunc_config.py:429(__init__)
     3000    0.002    0.000    0.002    0.000 {method 'discard' of 'set' objects}
     1000    0.001    0.000    0.001    0.000 __init__.py:1677(isEnabledFor)
     3000    0.001    0.000    0.001    0.000 {built-in method builtins.id}
     3000    0.001    0.000    0.001    0.000 {method 'add' of 'set' objects}
     3000    0.001    0.000    0.001    0.000 arrayprint.py:827(_none_or_positive_arg)
     3000    0.001    0.000    0.001    0.000 {built-in method _thread.get_ident}
     3000    0.001    0.000    0.001    0.000 {method 'copy' of 'dict' objects}
     4000    0.001    0.000    0.001    0.000 fromnumeric.py:2584(_amax_dispatcher)
     3000    0.001    0.000    0.001    0.000 fromnumeric.py:2709(_amin_dispatcher)
     1000    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 fromnumeric.py:2100(_sum_dispatcher)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 __init__.py:214(_acquireLock)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 __init__.py:223(_releaseLock)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 __init__.py:1663(getEffectiveLevel)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'acquire' of '_thread.RLock' objects}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'release' of '_thread.RLock' objects}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}
```

## recurser in python3.8/site-packages/numpy/core/arrayprint.py

```
def _formatArray(a, format_function, line_width, next_line_prefix,
                 separator, edge_items, summary_insert, legacy):
    """formatArray is designed for two modes of operation:

    1. Full output

    2. Summarized output

    """
    def recurser(index, hanging_indent, curr_width):
        """
        By using this local function, we don't need to recurse with all the
        arguments. Since this function is not created recursively, the cost is
        not significant
        """
        axis = len(index)
        axes_left = a.ndim - axis

        if axes_left == 0:
            return format_function(a[index])

        # when recursing, add a space to align with the [ added, and reduce the
        # length of the line by 1
        next_hanging_indent = hanging_indent + ' '
        if legacy == '1.13':
            next_width = curr_width
        else:
            next_width = curr_width - len(']')

        a_len = a.shape[axis]
        show_summary = summary_insert and 2*edge_items < a_len
        if show_summary:
            leading_items = edge_items
            trailing_items = edge_items
        else:
            leading_items = 0
            trailing_items = a_len

        # stringify the array with the hanging indent on the first line too
        s = ''

        # last axis (rows) - wrap elements if they would not fit on one line
        if axes_left == 1:
            # the length up until the beginning of the separator / bracket
            if legacy == '1.13':
                elem_width = curr_width - len(separator.rstrip())
            else:
                elem_width = curr_width - max(len(separator.rstrip()), len(']'))

            line = hanging_indent
            for i in range(leading_items):
                word = recurser(index + (i,), next_hanging_indent, next_width)
                s, line = _extendLine(
                    s, line, word, elem_width, hanging_indent, legacy)
                line += separator

            if show_summary:
                s, line = _extendLine(
                    s, line, summary_insert, elem_width, hanging_indent, legacy)
                if legacy == '1.13':
                    line += ", "
                else:
                    line += separator

            for i in range(trailing_items, 1, -1):
                word = recurser(index + (-i,), next_hanging_indent, next_width)
                s, line = _extendLine(
                    s, line, word, elem_width, hanging_indent, legacy)
                line += separator

            if legacy == '1.13':
                # width of the separator is not considered on 1.13
                elem_width = curr_width
            word = recurser(index + (-1,), next_hanging_indent, next_width)
            s, line = _extendLine(
                s, line, word, elem_width, hanging_indent, legacy)

            s += line

        # other axes - insert newlines between rows
        else:
            s = ''
            line_sep = separator.rstrip() + '\n'*(axes_left - 1)

            for i in range(leading_items):
                nested = recurser(index + (i,), next_hanging_indent, next_width)
                s += hanging_indent + nested + line_sep

            if show_summary:
                if legacy == '1.13':
                    # trailing space, fixed nbr of newlines, and fixed separator
                    s += hanging_indent + summary_insert + ", \n"
                else:
                    s += hanging_indent + summary_insert + line_sep

            for i in range(trailing_items, 1, -1):
                nested = recurser(index + (-i,), next_hanging_indent,
                                  next_width)
                s += hanging_indent + nested + line_sep

            nested = recurser(index + (-1,), next_hanging_indent, next_width)
            s += hanging_indent + nested

        # remove the hanging indent, and wrap in []
        s = '[' + s[len(hanging_indent):] + ']'
        return s

    try:
        # invoke the recursive part with an initial index and prefix
        return recurser(index=(),
                        hanging_indent=next_line_prefix,
                        curr_width=line_width)
    finally:
        # recursive closures have a cyclic reference to themselves, which
        # requires gc to collect (gh-10620). To avoid this problem, for
        # performance and PyPy friendliness, we break the cycle:
        recurser = None
```

## Update

My mistake of placing a logger statement with non-lazy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like something is formatting array(s) for printing, but I don't see where that's happening in your profiling.

Here's what I get when I use `ipython's` profiling `magic`:

```
In [7]: %prun softmax(np.arange(1000))
         22 function calls in 0.001 seconds

   Ordered by: internal time

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'reduce' of 'numpy.ufunc' objects}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 <ipython-input-2-4abb95d104cf>:1(softmax)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.001    0.001 {built-in method builtins.exec}
        2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 fromnumeric.py:71(<dictcomp>)
        2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 fromnumeric.py:70(_wrapreduction)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {built-in method numpy.arange}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 <__array_function__ internals>:2(amax)
        2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {built-in method numpy.core._multiarray_umath.implement_array_function}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 fromnumeric.py:2111(sum)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 <string>:1(<module>)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 fromnumeric.py:2617(amax)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 <__array_function__ internals>:2(sum)
        2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'items' of 'dict' objects}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {built-in method builtins.isinstance}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 fromnumeric.py:2612(_amax_dispatcher)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 fromnumeric.py:2106(_sum_dispatcher)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}
```